# PHPUnit Mocked method causes an exception

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have this function in a class

```
public function doSomething()
{
    try {
        $result = functionCall();
        if ($result === true) {
            $this->doGoodResult('With Success Message');
        } else {
            $this->doBadResult('ERROR - unable to do something');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->doBadResult('Did you divide by zero?');
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to test it with mocking out the extra functions

```
public function test_doSomthingWithBadResultGetsDoBadResultCalled()
{
    $ajc = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')
        ->setMethods(array('doBadResult'))
        ->setConstructorArgs(array('doSomething', array('input_var' => 0)))
        ->getMock();
    $ajc->expects($this->once())
        ->method('doBadResult')
        ->willReturn(null)
        ->with($this->contains('ERROR - unable to do something'));
    $ajc->doSomething();
}
```

and the problem is that I'm getting the following error from PHPUnit

```
MyClass::doBadResult('Did you divide by zero?') was not expected to be called more than once.
```

I'm not sure why, but it looks like the catch statement is being executed only when in this mock scenario.

Could anyone help me figure out why this is happening and especially how to set this up so that my test doesn't fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I found the Exception was `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and after some digging, it was in the `$this->contains('ERROR...')`

the answer is `$this->contains` should be `$this->stringContains`

Comment: This is the reason why it's important to check for specific Exception types when testing.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your need to do more digging in the future.  One of the problems that you have in your code is that you are catching the Base Exception type.

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->doBadResult('Did you divide by zero?');
}
```

When an assertion fails in PHPUnit, a `PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError` is thrown and is caught by PHPUnit.  This error extends the Base PHP Exception class.  So inside your try block when the mock object gets called, it checks the parameters that were used.  Since these are not correct, it throws the `PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError` which your catch statement grabs.  Which then calls the method on your mock that wasn't expected to be called.

Because of this, it would be possible for your test to end up passing incorrectly.  Because the failed assertion gets caught and handled by your code.  You should have a specific exception that your `catch` is looking for and any other exceptions get passed on to the appropriate level.